# Stopping Malicious Redirects Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, security

last week my wordpress website get redirected to a malicious website, i found some sql injections on my database and also a script on my index.php doing this redirect. I deleted all the malicious database entries and also the script in the index.php, some days later the index have again this script but i cant see the script again on my database. In the chrome inspector mode you can see the file causing the redirect but i cant find from what file my website its calling the script. I downloaded the whole site and use the search function of vscode but cant find the source of the infection. Anyone know how can i find the source/file of this GET?

[image]

The malicious redirect is js.cofounderspecials...

Comment: From my experience, attackers tends to hide those kinds of malicious code un base64 encoded strings.

Comment: i just used the firefox inspector, and in the network tab i can see the malicious js comes from my jquery.min.js, i just saw some code before the actual jquery code. Starts like eval(String.fromCharCode(118,97,114,32,115, + a lot of numbers, before the /*! jQuery v3.6.0 | comment that is the real start of the file. Any advice to avoid this type of injections?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't check for file uploads and extension before user uploads so the hacker uploaded a php and js file and edited db easily can u check for cronjobs and to see if there is any cronjob maliciously created?